# How to cover part of a image by background of another div?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have 2 divs, div1 contains an image and div2 contains some text. I'd like div2 with text to cover part of div1 image by setting `margin-top=-50px`. However, the background of div2 does not cover image in div1, how can I solve it?

Here is the code:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/795971591511347200/BE9ga9uY_400x400.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: -50px; background: red">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div>
          Here is some text with background color red. Text covers the image but background does not. 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Tried setting a z-index on the bottom div?

Comment: The image appears broken in the preview.

Comment: `position:relative` on the second div will do it

Answer (score 0):

```
position: absolute;
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/795971591511347200/BE9ga9uY_400x400.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="container-fluid" style="position:absolute; background: red">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div>
          Here is some text with background color red. Text covers the image but background does not. 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there a way to set the lower edge of div2 to match the lower edge of div1, and works responsively?